# Input text wrapped in an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input type text wrapped in an anchor like this:

```
<a href='https://www.google.ba/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=tIvlVYjiG8P9swHmzYfICw'>
    <input  id="email-field" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
</a>
```

I know what input is not allowed as child element of an anchor, but I need to handle this case if it is possible to be handled.

In all other browsers when i click on the input it redirects me to the anchor href. Just for IE, when I click nothing happened but text input is not focused, I need to double click on it to be able to type. And after I type the text I am not able to select it with mouse.

I resolved redirects for another browsers with next js line:

```
jQuery("#email-field").on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault();});
```

But it doesn't resolve anything for IE. I still need to double click on the field to be able to type and cannot select the text.

Is there any solution for this. I also tried this line with focus(), but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery("#email-field").on("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault();jQuery(this).focus();});
```

Comment: As you said, it is not allowed.  So whatever a browser does, it will do.  Why not fix your HTML?

Comment: No I cannot fix the HTML because I am not wrapping it. The input is outputted by my wordpress plugin but in same cases it being wrapped with anchor and I want to handle it if it is possible

Comment: Just create a div or add an image that looks like a text input inside of the anchor tag, then hide the text input...Don't be lazy, be semantic.

Comment: If you truly can't change your HTML - and really, you should be able to modify Wordpress to prevent such invalid HTML - you *could* try `$('a input').unwrap();` or `$('a input').insertBefore(function () return this.parentNode; });` - but despite this being, potentially, solvable with JavaScript avoiding the problem would be preferable.